# Ansible when condition always fails when a dictionary is there but it contains no elements

Tags: ansible

The problem that I am facing is the following: 
I have the following lines in my vars:

```
testparams:
  - { name: 'test' , test_type: 'test' }
```

What I need to do, from my tasks, is to include a file when this dictionary is defined. This is my code:

```
- include: test.yml
  when:  testparams is defined
```

It works when the whole definition of the dictionary is absent. But, when the dictionary definition is there but without any elements inside, this condition fails. I have tried with length, trying to get the type(just run it when it's Dictionary), but everything has failed so far.

Example of defined dictionary without elements:

```
testparams:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add what you tried with length?

Comment: My code: 
- include: test.yml
  when:  test|length > 0
--------------------
The error:
fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'testparams|length > 0' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if testparams|length > 0 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): object of type 'NoneType' has no len()\n\nTlem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: \"Kernel | Source variables\"\n  ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 1):

The definition of an empty list is done with brackets like in the following example:

```
testparams: []
```

And in your case, I would use the following test to have it work in all conditions:

```
when: testparams | default([]) | length > 0
```

Be aware that you are still responsible to sanitize your `testparams` definition as this might break if:

- you define a list of `testparams` that does not have the correct values
- you define `testparams` as a non empty string (which also has a `length > 0`).